# Embed an icon in between text in a text label with swift

Tags: ios, string, swift

I was able to embed the text into a label that looks like this with the code below. How do I add another string called LocationTo to the right side of the arrow?

```
var place = self.places[indexPath.row] as Place
    var attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    attachment.image = UIImage(named: "Right-50.png")
    var attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
    var arrowIcon = NSMutableAttributedString(string: place.Location)
    arrowIcon.appendAttributedString(attachmentString)
    cell.textLabel!.attributedText = arrowIcon
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your way,you just need to append Attribtue String

```
    arrowIcon.appendAttributedString(anotherString)
```